# Консолидация библиотек

Tags: linux, awk, library

Есть вывод `ldd`. Необходимо собрать все библиотеки в одну папку и возможно запаковать, так как их много, руками долго. Попрлбовал `awk` но мне не совсем понятно какой параметр нужно задавать чтобы забирать из строки только путь до библиотеки.
Я понимаю что конструкция должна выглядеть так `ldd binary |awk ???|cp ???|tar ???`

Comment: Задача сама по себе не очень разумная, если это собирание зависимостей. А что будет с линками на приликованные зависимости копируемых библиотек?

Comment: Если от забора, то имеется старинный `debian Hardy` и некий фраемворк, опытным путём было установлено, что и на свежем `whezy` всё работает, но вот незадача, никакого пакета/установщика под данное ПО нет. Поэтому  приходится переносить в ручную. В идеале хочется запилить deb пакет, чтобы просто ставить его на свежую систему. Поэтому и нужно в старой системе в автоматическом режиме собрать все зависимости. С линками придётся танцевать отдельно.

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что у вас нет исходников этого странного проекта?

Comment: Именно так..) И проект кстати платный, именуется caldera.

Comment: Ну так если платный, а вы же его купили, теребите техподдержку компании. Кстати, *caldera* мне ни о чём не говорит, за исключением старинного дистрибутива Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решен конструкция будет следующая:
`for i in $(ldd bynary|awk '{print $3}'); do cp -RH $i ~/lib_consolidate; done`
У меня скопировались и ссылки и оригинал.